# Как проверить строку на отсутствие ряда букв в RewriteCond (регулярные выражения, htaccess)?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Есть условие `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}`. В запрашиваемой строке (domain.com **/ru/apartment/228**) нужна проверка на наличие в начале «`/ru/`» (domain.com **/apartment/228**) и если его нет, то применяем `RewriteRule`. Пробовал с `!ru` и всякую ахинею по типу `!^[^\/ru\/]`.

Answer (score 1):

Экранировать слеши нужно

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/ru\/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ru/$1 [R,L]
```